# How to plot complex numbers in Mathematica?

Tags: plot, equation, complex-numbers, mathematica-8, wolframalpha

I have a very simple equation that I want to plot in Mathematica without Wolfram Alpha and I am having some trouble. This is the equation [ z^7 = 1 - i ] and I have used eq3 = Solve[{z^7 == 1 - i}, {z}] and found the answers but I want to plot them now but Plot function doesn't plot it. I tried CounterPlot and DensityPlot and neither of these functions is plotting it. please help!

Comment: Go search on the [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I didn't find anything helpful. I even tried the ParametricPlot

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving it like this
eq3 = Solve[z^7 == 1 - I, z];
Graphics[Point[ReIm[z /. eq3]]]
and 
ListPlot[ReIm[z /. eq3]]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
eq := z^7 == 1 - I
eq3 = Solve[eq, {z}] // Flatten // Values;
ListPlot[{Re[eq3], Im[eq3]}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True, PlotLabels -> {"Real part", "Imaginary part"}, AxesLabel -> {"Root number"}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19099457)

Comment: My answer actually does not require a clarification from the asker; it is just my way of providing the answer politely. I will edit it to conform with the rules. Thanks for the reminder.